# Google Script Substract Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I want to create a script function that I will use with daily triggers:

- function will subtract "Daily Fees" (a cell value that changes daily from "Open Trades" sheet) / from "Cash" (a cell in another sheet "Dashboard") and will set the value of the remaining Cash in the same cell (Cash from Dashboard)

**Formula -> 'Dashboard'!O5 = 'Dashboard'!O5 - 'Open Trades'!M4**

I'm very new to script and Here is my best try:

```
function substract(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dash = ss.getSheetName('Dashboard');
  var a = dash.getRange("O5").getvalue;
  
  var cash = ss.getSheetName('Open Trades');
  var b = cash.getRange("M4").getvalue;

 dash.getRange("O5").setvalue(a-b);
 }
```

However this gives me this error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getSheetName.
substract   @ Daily Fees.gs:3
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Just added my best effort until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script has several problems.

Start by replacing

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

by

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

also replace `getvalue` by `getValue()` and `setvalue(a-b)` by `setValue(a-b)`

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Comment: Followed your tips & also changed  ss.getSheetName to ss.getSheetByName and the script works now! Thanks